# spring security list of available roles

Tags: spring-security

I have been searching on google the list of available roles in spring security, but I haven't been able to get the complete list.

¿Could someone help me with this?

This is what I've found: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER, ROLE_VISITOR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of roles is not dictated by Spring Security, but is entirely up to what is required in a particular application.

The list of roles could for example be stored in the application's database. See for an example Spring Security's JdbcUserDetailsManager class which can be readily used to manage users, roles and authorities (privileges) in the database.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. Disappointingly the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html) doesn't say anything about this, leaving this up for speculation. I too assumed the role names were fixed as they appeared over and over again. One contradictory example would've been enough, but ... no.

Answer (score 1):

As Markus said there are no fixed number of roles in spring security.

Have a look at the javadoc for `org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority`.

Extending it allows you to override the `getAuthority` method from which you can return any role string you like.

Comment: Could SimpleGrantedAuthority do the same thing?